# Numerical procedure for finding steady eigenstate for a non-Hermitian effective model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, operators, condensed-matter, linear-algebra

I am working with an effective model describing an exciton-polariton system. I need to solve the Schrödinger equation (eigenvalue problem). To describe the presence of losses the diagonal terms are complex and also the parameters multiplying the first and second order derivatives of the differential equation system. This is making the matrix non-Hermitian and with complex eigenvalues. Has someone already worked with a similar problem? I need to discern the steady eigenstates I obtain from the numerical diagonalization of the space-discretized matrix.

-------------------------------------------Added later--------------------------------------------

I can make an explanatory example. I am dealing with the following Hamiltonian : $$ H = \begin{pmatrix}
    \alpha (\partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2) + \epsilon -i \gamma & \beta (\partial_x - i \partial_y)^2\\
     \beta (\partial_x + i \partial_y)^2 & \alpha (\partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2) + \epsilon -i \gamma,
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $\alpha, \epsilon, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\beta \in \mathbb{C}$.
Considering invariance in the $y$ direction I can reduce to a 1D problem with $k_x$ as a parameter and need to solve these coupled differential equations with periodic boundary conditions:
$$ \alpha \psi_{\pm}''(x) + (\epsilon -i \gamma) \psi_{\pm}(x) + \beta    \psi_{\mp}''(x)  \pm 2 \beta k_x \psi_{\mp}'(x) -k_x^2  \psi_{\mp}(x) = E \psi_{\pm}(x). $$

Comment: Please, provide some details. Once you get a discrete (or finite-dimensional) approximation of the problem, you should be able to solve the complex eigenvalue problem using a standard math library

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Finding the eigenvalues is not a problem. The question is more about physics. Since there is no possibility to order them, you cannot tell which one is the ground state and so on. To be eigenstates they also have to be normalized and orthogonal and, for a non-Hermitian matrix, the second one is not guaranteed.  How do I extrapolate physically meaningful info in this case from eigenvectors (not eigenstates) and eigenvalues?

Comment: IIRC a matrix has orthogonal eigenvectors if $A A^\dagger = A^\dagger A$ (which is a weaker condition than $A = A^\dagger$.)  Does your operator satisfy this condition?

Comment: Unfortunately, they don't commute. The effective model comes from a complicated Master equation where the physics is "clear", but also difficult to solve numerically. I was wondering if there is a sort of a posteriori check that I can do.

Comment: You should provide some details. As it stands it is impossible to saying anything.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Thank you. Because of your comment, I decided to add an example.

Comment: If $H^\dagger H \neq H H^\dagger$ the possible eigenvectors with different eigenvalues  may be non-orthogonal. Time evolution is not unitary, but this is accepted since there are losses. However,  it is difficult to distinguish between dynamics and losses...Even if you find a complete basis of eigenvectors, their physical intepretation is not trivial (to me, maybe everything is standard for experts on these issues).

Comment: @ValterMoretti knowing that there is not a precise mathematical prescription is also useful. At this point, I will consider more physical reasoning to put some order on the outputs of this model.